# Computer turns on but won't boot up

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer, boot

So here's the problem, my computer will turn on but it won't boot up. The monitor receives no  input signal and once the computer is on and I cannot turn it back off by pressing the power button down for three seconds, I have to physically unplug the power cable to shut it down. I am positive the problem is not with the monitor or the cable to the monitor because I tested it with my TV and a different VGA cable and yes, the TV and VGA cable do work. I should also explain that the computer has two fans a CPU fan and I guess just a general fan that blows air into the case. When I press the power button on the case, the CPU fan turns on for a couple of seconds then just turns off while the other fan continues to run.

I've had this computer for about eight years (yes I know that's a long time) and would like to save it before buying a new one. Nothing hardware wise has ever been changed or been messed with, every hardware component is stock. The software side of things is different as I've upgraded the OS to Windows 8 from Windows Vista (my mom had no idea what she was buying at the time). So I would really like to save anything that will restore the computer to factory settings until after I've exhausted other potential solutions.

[Here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01619708&tmp_track_link=ot_faqs/top_issues/en_us/c01619708/loc:4&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=3872431) is the product specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the plugs that go from the power and reset buttons are set firmly in their motherboard sockets.

Also, make sure that all the plugs that go from the power supply unit are firmly set in their sockets. In fact, if there's a wire inside your case that has a plug, take it out, clean it, and put it back in where it belongs (taking pictures beforehand helps to remember where exactly)

If that doesn't help, Take out the graphics card, clean the connectors and put it back in firmly.

As a last resort you might try pushing down on the motherboard while the computer is running to see whether the CPU fan starts up when you apply pressure on a certain area. If so, use something to constantly push it. That helped me once when I was experiencing a very similar issue on an old motherboard. Be warned, though, that this is potentially dangerous to you, as you might get shocked (at least wear rubber gloves), or to your computer as you might damage it if you push down too hard. I don't take responsibility for the result of this, should you decide to do it.